# Conditional in list not evaluating

Tags: ocaml

I'm a beginner teaching myself OCaml with Real World OCaml.

For some reason, the line

```
let contains_1 l =
    if List.mem l 1 then true;;
```

Throws the error

Error: This expression has type equal:(int -> int -> bool) -> bool                                                                                                                      but an expression was expected of type bool

This example seems incredibly simple, and I can't figure out what is going on. It seems like `List.mem l 1` is not evaluating and just sitting there as a function? My OCaml version is 4.05.0. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code cannot work because you are missing an else-case. In OCaml, a `if` without an `else` means a totally different thing. So you could write your function as

```
let contains_1 l =
  if List.mem l 1 ~equal:(=) then true else false
```

But, you don't need to do

```
if <boolean> then true else false
```

because the whole expression will equal `<boolean>` anyways.

---

Hence, here is what you're trying to write

```
let contains_1 l =
  List.mem l 1 ~equal:(=)
```

This evaluates to

```
val contains_1 : int list -> bool = <fun>
```

and works as intended:

```
contains_1 [1;2;3;4];;
- : bool = true

contains_1 [2;3;4;5];;
- : bool = false
```

Answer (score -3):

Resolved! I was returning a partial

```
let contains_1 l =
    if List.mem l 1 ~equal=(=) then true;;
```

works as intended.

Comment: How is the `then true` working? The typer should be expecting an `else` clause in non-unit cases (also, you can strip the `if` altogether and just return the boolean).

Comment: I downvoted because your code is still invalid. See my answer for details.